# Hello, World! Google app engine issues

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am on a mac and am attempting to use google app engine for the first time. I have the correct version of python. I created a new application and named it 'helloworld' and left all the files that are automatically generated when you create a new application unchanged. After pressing run, I was able to view the output 'Hello, world!' on my browser at localhost:8081; however, when I deploy the application there is the following error in the log:

```
*** Running appcfg.py with the following flags:
    --no_cookies --email=killianjackson99@gmail.com --passin update
02:28 PM Application: heythereworld; version: 1
02:28 PM Host: appengine.google.com
02:28 PM 
Starting update of app: heythereworld, version: 1
02:28 PM Getting current resource limits.
02:28 PM Scanning files on local disk.
Error 404: --- begin server output ---
This application does not exist (app_id=u'heythereworld').
--- end server output ---
Password for killianjackson99@gmail.com: If deploy fails you might need to 'rollback' manually.
The "Make Symlinks..." menu option can help with command-line work.
*** appcfg.py has finished with exit code 1 ***
```

Does anyone have any thoughts as to what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before deploy your application on the Google app engine server you need to create a project in the Google Developers Console. https://console.developers.google.com/project
All you need to know about de deployment is hier: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/uploading

Answer (score 0):

Create your project in the Developer Console. 
Add the name you entered in the Console in app.yaml:

```
application: my_app_name
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.application
```